# Проблема с методами доступа к private полям;

Tags: c++, ооп, объекты

В классе ,в private полях есть объект другого класса. У этого объекта есть закрытые поля.Есть методы доступа к этим полям.Но они отказываются работать.На последних строчках кода вылетает программа. Что то делаю не так, но знаний не хватает понять что именно. Или есть другие способы достучаться до private полей? Friend классы в моем случае применять нельзя.

---

#### computer_network.h

```cpp
class computers_network{   //класс управления узлами
    public:
        computers_network();
    private:
        int length;
        Node *Tail;      
};
```

---

#### Node.h

```cpp
class Node{  // Узел
    public:
        Node();

        //методы доступа к закрытым данным
        Node getNext(){
            return *next;
        }

        Node getPrev(){
            return *prev;
        }

        void setNext(Node temp){
            *next = temp;
        }
        void setPrev(Node temp){
            *prev = temp;
        }

    private:
        Node *next; //указатели на соседние элементы
        Node *prev;

        computer *array[4]; // массив компьютеров
};
```

---

#### Computer_network.cpp

```cpp
    //...
    Node *temp = new Node();
    Tail->setNext(*temp);  //вот здесь программа вылетает
    temp->setPrev(*Tail);   // и так тоже
    *Tail = temp->getPrev(); //аналогично
    //...
```

Comment: Не реализуете конструкторы и операторы копирования и перемещения, используете сырые указатели, передаете нетривиальные объекты по значению.

Comment: @VTT понятно,что ничего не понятно

Comment: Node *Tail; это указатель на какой то объект. В данный момент он не на что не указывает. Tail->setNext(*temp); и в других местах вы пытаетесь манипулировать по средством указателя объектом, на который указывает указатель. А так, как указатель пустой, то и оперировать не чем

Comment: в файле Computer_network.cpp напишите Tail = new Node(); что то типа этого

Comment: @helldrg спасибо, проблема именно в этом была. Еще нужно next = new Node(); писать.